# laravel 5.1 filter using pivot table

Tags: many-to-many, pivot-table, laravel-5.1

Hi i am developing job portal but facing a problem in pivot table filtering. i have a table like below

**personal_details**

```
id
name
sex
dob
nationality
visa_status
```

**vacancies**

```
id
name
description
created_at
updated_at
```

which have a many-to-many relation with pivot table. 
Data here is inserted when a job-seeker apply for a vacancy

**personal_detail_vacancy**

```
id
personal_detail_id
vacancy_id
created_at
updated_at
```

**PersonalDetail model**

```
class PersonalDetail extends Model
{

    public function vacancies()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Vacancy')->withTimestamps();

 }
}
```

**Vacancy model**

```
class Vacancy extends Model
{
    public function personal_details()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\PersonalDetail');

}
```

**what i want to do is select all personal detail who have applied for a job(in any vacancies) in a particular date

i tried**

```
$personal_details = PersonalDetail::with(array('vacancies' => function($query){

       $query->wherePivot('created_at', '2015-11-10 11:33:24'); 

       }))->get();
```

**but it is not filtering the date
ANY IDEA?**

Answer (score 1):

well solved this by using

```
$personal_details = PersonalDetail::whereHas('vacancies',function($query)
      {
             $query->where('created_at','2015-11-10 11:33:24'); 
      })->get();
```

it was not working before. The problem was i had 'created_at' field in vacancies table also.